# fallo en parse, decimales largos

Tags: javascript, html

estoy realizando un programa en javascript que calcula cantidades de articulos, y tengo un fallo justo a la hora de emplear decimales, como veis en mi codigo, usa parseFloats para que no me de problemas a la hora de usarlos, sin embargo, me saca como resultado decimales excesivamente largos, mi segundo problema también es que al intentar aplicar un descuento, y luego procedo a borrar los articulos tras ello, me saca por pantalla decimales aún mas largo y no retorna la cantidad a 0 cuando elimino los productos sino que me saca numeros negativos muy extraños ¿sabeis a que puede deberse estos errores? he intentado solucionarlo haciendo uso de toFixed(2), pero no se si es que o los coloco mal o no me funcionan, los he quitado del codigo, pero los usaba en todos los calculos.

```js
//INSERTAR DATOS: Agregamos función click al identificador agregarLinea
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $(document).on('click', '#agregarLinea', function (event) 
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        //Especificamos los valores que vamos a tomar
        $valorProducto = $("#producto").val();
        $valorCantidad = $("#cantidad").val();
        $valorPrecioUnitario = $("#precio-unitario").val();
        $valorDescuento = $("#descuento").val();
        $valorTotal = $("#total-linea").val();

        //insertamos los contenidos
        $("tbody").append("<tr class='info'>"
            + "<td> " + $valorProducto + " </td>"
            + "<td class='valorCantidad'> " + $valorCantidad + " </td>"
            + "<td class='valorPrecioUnitario'> " + $valorPrecioUnitario + " </td>"
            + "<td class='valorDescuento'> " + $valorDescuento + " </td>"
            + "<td class='valorTotal'> " + $valorTotal + " </td>"
            + "<td> <button type'button' class='borrar btn-success'> Borrar </button>"
            + "</tr>"
        );
        //CALCULAR EL TOTAL
        //base imponible es 0 y se suma al total que inicialmente es 0, hasta que metamos un costo
        $cantidadActualizada = parseFloat($("#base-imponible").text()) + parseFloat($valorTotal);
        $("#base-imponible").text($cantidadActualizada);
        //calculamos el iva y lo sumamos a la factura del producto/s
        $iva = ($cantidadActualizada * 1.21) - $cantidadActualizada;
        $("#iva").text($iva);
        $totalFact = $cantidadActualizada + $iva;
        $("span#total").text($totalFact);
        //establecemos la fecha actual de las compras
        let date = new Date();
        let time = "Articulo: " + $valorProducto + " añadido el "
            + date.getUTCDate() + "/"
            + (date.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "/"
            + date.getUTCFullYear() + " a las "
            + date.getHours() + ":"
            + date.getMinutes() + ":"
            + date.getSeconds();
        $(".container").append("<p>" + time + "</p>");


    });

    /*BORRAR FILA*/
    //agregamos evento click al botón borrar
    $(document).on('click', ".borrar", function () {
        $valor = $(this).parent().siblings(".valorTotal").text();
        //restamos los valores de cada apartado para dejarlo todo de vuelta a 0
        $cantidadActualizada = parseFloat($("#base-imponible").text()) - parseFloat($valor);
        $("#base-imponible").text($cantidadActualizada);
        $iva = ($cantidadActualizada * 1.21) - $cantidadActualizada;
        $("#iva").text($iva);
        //igualamos a 0 la factura
        $totalFact = $cantidadActualizada + $iva;
        $("span#total").text($totalFact);
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

    //ESTABLECEMOS DESCUENTO A UN PRODUCTO
    $(document).on('mouseout', "#descuento, #precio-unitario", function () {
        //Tomamos cada uno de los valores de cada celda
        $valorCantidad = $("#cantidad").val();
        $valorPrecioUnitario = $("#precio-unitario").val();
        //aplicamos el descuento
        $valorDescuento = $("#descuento").val();
        //calculamos
        $("#total-linea").val($valorCantidad * $valorPrecioUnitario * (1 - $valorDescuento / 100));

    });

    //APLICAMOS EL DESCUENTO A TODAS LAS FILAS
    $(document).on('click', "#aplicarDescuento", function (event) 
    {event.preventDefault();
        //tomamos el valor del descuento
        $descuentoLineas = $("#descuento-lineas").val();
        //leemos el valor aplicado
        $(".valorDescuento").text($descuentoLineas);

        //Calculamos el descuento
        $(".info").each(function () {
            //buscamos y leemos
            $valorCantidad = $(this).find(".valorCantidad").text();
            $valorPrecioUnitario = $(this).find(".valorPrecioUnitario").text();
            //calculamos el descuento
            $valorTotal = parseFloat($valorCantidad) * parseFloat($valorPrecioUnitario) * (1 - parseFloat($descuentoLineas) / 100);
            $(this).children('.valorTotal').text($valorTotal);
        });
        $refreshAmount = 0;
        $iva = 0;
        $('.valorTotal').each(function () {
            $parse = parseFloat($(this).text());
            $refreshAmount += $parse;
            $("#base-imponible").text($refreshAmount);
    
        });
        $iva = ($refreshAmount * 1.21) - $refreshAmount;
        $("#iva").text($iva);
        $totalFact = $refreshAmount + $iva;
        $("span#total").text($totalFact);

    });
    
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>Práctica 2 | DWC | Grupo Studium</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 mt-5">
                    <h3>Introducción de productos en la factura</h3>
                    <table class="table table-striped mt-4">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th>Cantidad</th>
                                <th>Precio unitario</th>
                                <th>Descuento (%)</th>
                                <th>Precio total</th>
                                <th>Opciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="producto" id="producto" /></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" /></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="precio-unitario" id="precio-unitario" /></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="descuento" id="descuento" /></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="total-linea" id="total-linea" readonly /></td>
                                <td><a href="" id="agregarLinea" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-right" colspan="4">Base imponible</td>
                                <td class="text-right"><span id="base-imponible">0</span>€</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-right" colspan="4" data-iva="0.21">IVA 21%</td>
                                <td class="text-right"><span id="iva">0</span>€</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="descuento-lineas" id="descuento-lineas" placeholder="%" /></td>
                                <td colspan="2"><a href="" id="aplicarDescuento" class="btn btn-info">Aplicar descuento a todas las líneas</a></td>
                                <td class="text-right"><strong>Total factura</strong></td>
                                <td class="text-right"><strong><span id="total">0</span>€</strong></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src='facturas.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para arreglar decimales con JS es sencillo usando la Funcion **toFixed()**

```
 $totalFact = $refreshAmount + $iva;
 $("span#total").text(parseFloat($totalFact).toFixed(2));
```

Dicha Funcion recibe un parametro que es la cantidad de decimales que necesitas

Usando tu codigo imprimirá algo asi:

```
//7.26€
```

Te dejo tu código modificado:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>Práctica 2 | DWC | Grupo Studium</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 mt-5">
                    <h3></h3>
                    <table class="table table-striped mt-4">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th>Cantidad</th>
                                <th>Precio unitario</th>
                                <th>Descuento (%)</th>
                                <th>Precio total</th>
                                <th>Opciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="producto" id="producto" /></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" /></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="precio-unitario" id="precio-unitario" /></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="descuento" id="descuento" /></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="total-linea" id="total-linea" readonly /></td>
                                <td><a href="" id="agregarLinea" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-right" colspan="4">Base imponible</td>
                                <td class="text-right"><span id="base-imponible">0</span>€</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-right" colspan="4" data-iva="0.21">IVA 21%</td>
                                <td class="text-right"><span id="iva">0</span>€</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="descuento-lineas" id="descuento-lineas" placeholder="%" /></td>
                                <td colspan="2"><a href="" id="aplicarDescuento" class="btn btn-info">Aplicar descuento a todas las líneas</a></td>
                                <td class="text-right"><strong>Total factura</strong></td>
                                <td class="text-right"><strong><span id="total">0</span>€</strong></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $(document).on('click', '#agregarLinea', function (event) 
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        //Especificamos los valores que vamos a tomar
        $valorProducto = $("#producto").val();
        $valorCantidad = $("#cantidad").val();
        $valorPrecioUnitario = $("#precio-unitario").val();
        $valorDescuento = $("#descuento").val();
        $valorTotal = $("#total-linea").val();

        //insertamos los contenidos
        $("tbody").append("<tr class='info'>"
            + "<td> " + $valorProducto + " </td>"
            + "<td class='valorCantidad'> " + $valorCantidad + " </td>"
            + "<td class='valorPrecioUnitario'> " + $valorPrecioUnitario + " </td>"
            + "<td class='valorDescuento'> " + $valorDescuento + " </td>"
            + "<td class='valorTotal'> " + $valorTotal + " </td>"
            + "<td> <button type'button' class='borrar btn-success'> Borrar </button>"
            + "</tr>"
        );
        //CALCULAR EL TOTAL
        //base imponible es 0 y se suma al total que inicialmente es 0, hasta que metamos un costo
        $cantidadActualizada = parseFloat($("#base-imponible").text()) + parseFloat($valorTotal);
        $("#base-imponible").text(parseFloat($cantidadActualizada).toFixed(2));
        //calculamos el iva y lo sumamos a la factura del producto/s
        $iva = ($cantidadActualizada * 1.21) - $cantidadActualizada;
        var total_iva=parseFloat($iva).toFixed(2);
        $("#iva").html(total_iva<0?0:total_iva);
        $totalFact = $cantidadActualizada + $iva;
        $("span#total").text(parseFloat($totalFact).toFixed(2));
        //establecemos la fecha actual de las compras
        let date = new Date();
        let time = "Articulo: " + $valorProducto + " añadido el "
            + date.getUTCDate() + "/"
            + (date.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "/"
            + date.getUTCFullYear() + " a las "
            + date.getHours() + ":"
            + date.getMinutes() + ":"
            + date.getSeconds();
        $(".container").append("<p>" + time + "</p>");


    });

    /*BORRAR FILA*/
    //agregamos evento click al botón borrar
    $(document).on('click', ".borrar", function () {
        $valor = $(this).parent().siblings(".valorTotal").text();
        //restamos los valores de cada apartado para dejarlo todo de vuelta a 0
        $cantidadActualizada = parseFloat($("#base-imponible").text()) - parseFloat($valor);
        var total_base=parseFloat($cantidadActualizada).toFixed(2);

        $("#base-imponible").html(total_base<0?0:total_base);
        $iva = ($cantidadActualizada * 1.21) - $cantidadActualizada;
        var total_iva=parseFloat($iva).toFixed(2);

        $("#iva").html(total_iva<0.001?0:total_iva);
        //igualamos a 0 la factura
        $totalFact = $cantidadActualizada + $iva;
        var total_mostrar=parseFloat($totalFact).toFixed(2);
        $("span#total").html(total_mostrar<0?0:total_mostrar);
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

    //ESTABLECEMOS DESCUENTO A UN PRODUCTO
    $(document).on('mouseout', "#descuento, #precio-unitario", function () {
        //Tomamos cada uno de los valores de cada celda
        $valorCantidad = $("#cantidad").val();
        $valorPrecioUnitario = $("#precio-unitario").val();
        //aplicamos el descuento
        $valorDescuento = $("#descuento").val();
        //calculamos
        $("#total-linea").val($valorCantidad * $valorPrecioUnitario * (1 - $valorDescuento / 100));

    });

    //APLICAMOS EL DESCUENTO A TODAS LAS FILAS
    $(document).on('click', "#aplicarDescuento", function (event) 
    {event.preventDefault();
        //tomamos el valor del descuento
        $descuentoLineas = $("#descuento-lineas").val();
        //leemos el valor aplicado
        $(".valorDescuento").text($descuentoLineas);

        //Calculamos el descuento
        $(".info").each(function () {
            //buscamos y leemos
            $valorCantidad = $(this).find(".valorCantidad").text();
            $valorPrecioUnitario = $(this).find(".valorPrecioUnitario").text();
            //calculamos el descuento
            $valorTotal = parseFloat($valorCantidad) * parseFloat($valorPrecioUnitario) * (1 - parseFloat($descuentoLineas) / 100);
            $(this).children('.valorTotal').text($valorTotal);
        });
        $refreshAmount = 0;
        $iva = 0;
        $('.valorTotal').each(function () {
            $parse = parseFloat($(this).text());
            $refreshAmount += $parse;
            var total_base=parseFloat($refreshAmount).toFixed(2);
            $("#base-imponible").html(total_base<0?0:total_base);
    
        });
        $iva = ($refreshAmount * 1.21) - $refreshAmount;
        var total_iva=parseFloat($iva).toFixed(2);
        $("#iva").html(total_iva<0?0:total_iva);
        $totalFact = $refreshAmount + $iva;

        var total_mostrar=parseFloat($totalFact).toFixed(2);
        $("span#total").html(total_mostrar<0?0:total_mostrar);

    });
    
})

</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ¡me funciona!, sin embargo el problema del descuento aún persiste y no se a que se debe que siga ocurriendo, al añadir varios productos y aplicar el descuento, al borrarlos se queda un 0.01 extraño cuando deberia de ser 0 ¿no?

Comment: Estuve probando y el descuento me lo saca bien.. en que parte es que te da ese error?

Comment: Agrega 3 productos donde cantidad, precio y descuento sean 1 (el precio total debería dar 0.99). Luego borralos, y notarás como aparece el segundo error que comenta

Comment: Si, mira, prueba añadir 5 productos, y luego agrega un descuento para aplicarlo a todas las lineas, y luego procede a borrarlos uno a uno, puedo adjuntar una imagen si asi lo quieres para que se muestre mejor.

Comment: He actualizado el script, coloque 4 productos que todos daban 0.99 y los borre y al parecer no me da error, deje el codigo aca https://jsfiddle.net/nrwkp1fx/ para que prueben y me digan donde da error :)

Comment: Efectivamente, ya no aparece el error. ;)

Comment: ¡Ahora! ya no salen numeros raros y extraños. Lo curioso es que funciona con cualquier cantidad decimal, pero no se porque he probado hacer lo mismo, añadir 4 productos por valor de 0.5, y me sale un -0.02 de la factura total. He probado meterle un condicional al totalFactura que si es <0 me lo igual a 0, pero no me dio resultado.

Comment: Entiendo, ya modifique el script con esa validación

Comment: Amigo, no sabes cuanto me has ayudado a comprender mucho mejor mi programa, en serio, ¡muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Para ayudarnos, saludos! :D